# Count # of arrays in an array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I am trying to find the total number of arrays in my given array. I have tried using the `count()` function and the `sizeof()` function but both say that there are 66666 arrays when I know there are only 5 (I think this is because it is in a while loop).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo count($row);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions anymore cause they're deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. You won't have an array in the array `$row`. Just scalar data types (database column values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this funciton

mysql_num_rows — Get number of rows in result

documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

As others suggested I would look into at least the mysqli or preferably PDO instead of just mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [mysql_fetch_lengths](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-lengths.php) to find the length of the returned fields length or you can use [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find the length of the returned rows .

The code will be something like this.

```
$lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths($result);
print_r($lengths);
```

and you are getting 66666 as result because everytime the number 6 is getting added to the prevoius output. I mean try `echo count($row \n);` and you will get the following output

```
6
6
6
6
6
```

Please refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919667/mysql-selecting-count-of-rows-as-extra-column) to better understand.